# NullReferenceException + EF6 + SQL Express

Tags: .net

Buenas noches soy nuevo con Entity Framework y tengo el siguiente
problema, el codigo debbugea bien hasta el punto de
new AmbuwebEntities()  ;
Que va hasta  base("name=AmbuwebEntities") y tira Null Reference
dejo las clases en cuestion:

```
   namespace proyecto.entityfw.AccountEF{
   
    public class AccountDACEF : IDisposable{
        private AmbuwebEntities ctx;
        public AccountDACEF (){
            ctx = new AmbuwebEntities();
        }
        public string EncDecr(AccountDAO Account){          
                try{
                    var c = ctx.Calles.Find("1");
                    return null;
                }catch (Exception e) { throw e; }
            
        }
          namespace proyecto{     
          using System;
          using System.Data.Entity;
          using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

           public partial class AmbuwebEntities : DbContext{
            public AmbuwebEntities(): base("name=AmbuwebEntities"){
             }

         protected override void 
            OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){
             throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
         }
      }   
    public virtual DbSet<Calles> Calles { get; set; }
   Al hacer new AmbuwebEntities(); siempre sale por nullReference 
   exception.
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, mostra tu error completo y tambien que tiene el create de esa clase...